# How to enable live-reload in a dockerised FastAPI application using Docker Compose

Tags: docker-compose, fastapi

I have FastAPI app running in docker docker container. It works well except only one thing, the app doesn't reload if any changes are made in the source code. The changes are applied only if the container is restarted.

Here is the source code of my application so how do I ensure my containerised application automatically reloads each time I make some changes to the source code?

**main.py**

```py
from typing import Optional
    
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
    
app = FastAPI()
    
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

    
@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Optional[str] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000, reload=True)
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"
    
services:
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "50009:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
```

Answer (score 17):

this works for me

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  people:
    container_name: people
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --reload
    environment:
      DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    ports:
      - 8008:8000
    restart: on-failure
```

this is my directory structure

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
├── app
│   └── main.py
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

make sure `working_dir` and `volumes` section's `- ./app:/code/app` match

example run:

```sh
docker-compose up --build

...
Attaching to people
people    | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/code/app']
```

Comment: thanks man, adding volumes did job for me!

Answer (score 9):

Are you starting the container with `docker compose up`? This is working for me with hot reload at `http://127.0.0.1`.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  bff:
    container_name: bff
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/app
    command: uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --reload
    environment:
      DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    restart: on-failure
```

Also, I don't have your final two lines, `if __name__ ==` etc., in my app. Not sure if that would change anything.

Answer (score 4):

I found this solution that worked for me, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74307912/2369865).

In the [watchfiles documentation](https://watchfiles.helpmanual.io/api/watch/#watchfiles.watch--force-polling) it is understood that the detection relies on file system notifications, and I think that via docker its events are not launched when using a volume.

> Notify will fall back to file polling if it can't use file system
> notifications

So you have to tell watchfiles to force the polling, that's what you did in your test python script with the parameter force_polling and that's why it works:

for changes in watch('/code', force_polling=True):
Fortunately in the documentation we are given the possibility to force the polling via the environment variable **WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING**. Add this environment variable to your docker-compose.yml and auto-reload will work:

```
services:
  fastapi-dev:
    image: myimagename:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
      - ./static:/static
      - ./templates:/templates
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${HTTP_PORT:-8080}:80"
    environment:
      - WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING=true
```

Answer (score 1):

### Too Long; Didn't Read

You need [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) configured in the `docker-compose.yml` file for `docker` to know and understand where and which source code to copy to the container's filesystem. Else the container is completely isolated from the host's filesystem and would have no clue about the latest changes to the source code. In other words, even `uvicorn` wouldn't be aware of any changes and the `uvicorn.run(..., reload=True)` is pretty much useless any way!

If you don't configure bind mounts, only a complete rebuild of the container will copy the latest changes to the source code.

### Clearing Basic Misconceptions

There are a couple of misunderstandings you seem to have about the tools in questions i.e Docker Compose, Uvicorn and FastAPI, so let's clear those first.

1. When `uvicorn` is invoked programmatically, its not necessary to invoke it in the command-line interface once again! You can simply, execute the script like this - `python -m main` and you're good to go.
2. You need to utilise bind mounts to **properly** enable live-reload on your project. In other words, the contents of your source code should be mounted to the container's filesystem.

All of these might sound complicated but bear with me till the end of the answer and the concepts will hopefully be clearer by then.

### An Example Mini Project

Here is an example mini project which you can copy as-is on to your local development environment for practice. And ensure you've your Python [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) activated by invoking the `python -m venv .venv && source .venv/bin/activate` (`Python3` on Debian/Ubuntu) set of commands!

Our simple example project's directory structure will look somewhat like this:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── main.py
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Then copy this minimal FastAPI application to a `main.py` file:

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def say_hello() -> dict[str, str]:
    """Print a "Hello World!" message."""
    return {"message": "Hello World!"}


def main() -> None:
    """Invoke the entrypoint function of the script."""
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And this `Dockerfile` to build the image for our custom FastAPI container to be based on.

```
# Set some global variables to be used across the Dockerfile
ARG WORKDIR="/app"
ARG APPNAME="my-app"

# See the following article to learn more about choosing the right base image
# https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images
FROM python:3.11-slim-bookworm

# Refetch the variable names (optional but necessary for multi-stage builds)
ARG WORKDIR
ARG APPNAME

# Configure Python to not buffer "stdout" or create .pyc files
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Update the system and ensure its ready for usage
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
    gcc-11=11.3.0-12 build-essential=12.9

# See the following article for information on this regards:
# https://pythonspeed.com/articles/root-capabilities-docker-security
RUN adduser --system --group --home ${WORKDIR} ${APPNAME}
USER ${APPNAME}

# Set the working directory to a secure non-root location
WORKDIR /home/${APPNAME}${WORKDIR}

# Copy the source code to the container
COPY . .

# Install the runtime dependencies using pip
RUN python -m pip install pip~=23.0 --upgrade --no-cache-dir && \
    python -m pip install --requirement "requirements.txt" --no-cache-dir

# Expose the port used by the application so that its accessible outside the container
EXPOSE 8000

# Invoke the Python module to start the backend application
CMD [ "python", "-m", "main" ]
```

The example `Dockerfile` above is derived from this [example multi-stage Docker build](https://gist.github.com/Jarmos-san/11bf22c59d26daf0aa5223bdd50440da) as a source of reference.

Since a typical full-stack application can have multiple Docker Containers (each with its own `Dockerfile` and ensuing Docker Image), its common to have a single `docker-compose.yml` file. This helps managing multiple Docker containers up and running with a few set of commands instead of multiple ones.

Here are some recommended readings to learn more about the actual use case of Docker Compose commands in the following resources:

1. Official Docker tutorial on "[Multiple Container Applications](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/)" and "[Using Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/08_using_compose/)".
2. The official FastAPI [documentation on containerising applications](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/) using Docker.

That said, here is a simple and minimal `docker-compose.yml` file to copy-paste on your local development environment.

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /home/my-app/app
```

Our mini example project till now has been **VERY** comprehensive and if you've been patient till now, the next section provides a detailed line-by-line explanation of the mini project's source code.

### Explaining the Mini Project's Source Code

The source code of our project is rather simple and if you've copied everything properly, it should work without any errors. And if there is no error, here is what you should ideally see when you open http://localhost on your browser.

[image]

The `main.py` script contains a single endpoint (which by the way is *root* or `/`) and it returns a JSON response. Further, the script programatically invokes `uvicorn` to run the webserver on the default port (i.e 8000) and it reloads the server when the source code changes.

The `uvicorn.run()` function accepts the `host` argument whose value is set to `"0.0.0.0"` to make the application accept connections outside the container. You can read more about it in the official documentations on [socket binding](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#socket-binding).

```py
# ...rest of the code

def main() -> None:
    """Invoke the entrypoint function of the script."""
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", reload=True)

# ...rest of the code
```

The `Dockerfile` we have above creates a Docker Image to build our Docker Container on. It is configured to install the necessary dependencies (both for application runtime, Python's build dependencies and `pip`). Besides, the image also configures the container to run our FastAPI application in a non-root environment for security concerns. And when everything is ready, it invokes the script using the `python -m main` command.

```
# ...rest of the Dockerfile

CMD [ "python", "-m", "main" ]
```

Invoking Python script from within the `Dockerfile` itself keeps the `docker-compose.yml` file clutter-free and easy to refer to when the need arises.

Now for the crux of the entire project, the `docker-compose.yml` file which is how we manage the entire application (both the FastAPI, a possible database and frontend services or more).

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /home/my-app/app
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file instructs `docker` to create a service named `backend` which is basically our FastAPI project. You can have more services each with its own configurations and `docker compose` will create containers based on those configurations. You can read more about the Docker Compose "*Service*" specification here - [Docker Compose Services](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/).

The `backend` service creates the container using the `Dockerfile` build context found in the current working directory. And it maps port `80` on the host to port `8000` (the default for `uvicorn`) on the container. Further, the container is also configured to always restart after certain events.

To get live-reload working, as the question enquires, the Compose file is configured with a bind mount. The bind mount's source is the current working directory (where the `main.py` script is located) and it is mounted to the absolute path `/home/my-app/app`. The absolute path is where the Dockerfile configures docker to copy the `main.py` from the source code to the container's filesystem.

Hence, without bind mounts, the container's filesystem is completely isolated from the host and any changes made to the source code on the host's filesystem will not be copied to the container. Only a complete rebuild of the container will ensure the latest changes are copied there!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi](https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi) images, defining `entrypoint` looks like the most elegant way to do this:

```
myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    entrypoint: /start-reload.sh
    ...
```