# Uvicorn --reload using WatchFiles is not working for FastAPI in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi, uvicorn

I am developing a FastAPI app. It is running on Uvicorn in a Docker container using docker-compose.

I want to include some files other than `*.py` to trigger the auto reload while in development.

[According to the docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#development) Uvicorn needs the optional dependency WatchFiles installed to be able to use the `--reload-include` flag, which would enable me to include other file types to trigger a reload. However, when WatchFiles is installed (with Uvicorn confirming by printing this info at start up: `Started reloader process [1] using WatchFiles`) **no auto reloads happen at all.** Mind you, this is independent of changes to the run command, with or without the include flag.

Without WatchFiles installed, Uvicorn's default auto reload works as intended for just `*.py` files.

### What I've got

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code

CMD ["uvicorn", "package.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]
```

This is the docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  fastapi-dev:
    image: myimagename:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
      - ./static:/static
      - ./templates:/templates
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${HTTP_PORT:-8080}:80"
```

(I need a docker-compose file because of some services required later on.)

The most basic FastAPI app:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def index():
    raise HTTPException(418)
```

Mind you, this is probably of no concern as the problem does not seem to be related to FastAPI.

requirements.txt:

```
fastapi~=0.85
pydantic[email]~=1.10.2
validators~=0.20.0
uvicorn~=0.18
watchfiles
python-decouple==3.6
python-multipart
pyotp~=2.7
wheezy.template~=3.1
```

### How did I try to resolve this issue?

I tried using `command: uvicorn package.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload` in docker-compose.yml instead of `CMD [...]` in the Dockerfile, which unsurprisingly changed nothing.

I created a file `watch.py` to test if WatchFiles works:

```py
from watchfiles import watch

for changes in watch('/code', force_polling=True):
    print(changes)
```

And…in fact it does work. Running it from the container in Docker CLI prints all the changes made. (`python -m watch`) And btw it works just as fine async/using asyncio. So it is probably nothing to do with the file system/share/mount within Docker.

### So…

How do I fix it? What is wrong with Uvicorn(?) I need to check for other file types e.g. `*.html` in `/templates`. Do I have to get WatchFiles to work or are there other ways? If I do, how?

Comment: While not an answer to your question; uvicorn does not need to be reloaded for FastAPI app to pick up changes in a template - those templates are usually read from disk on every request. Have you configured any caching for the templates?

Comment: Good point, thanks. wheezy.template stores the templates in memory from the point at which each individual template is used, it seems. I would have to instantiate the view render engine on every request, which I think would be more resource friendly not to. Or is it? Does it even matter?

Comment: For now I opted to create the render engine on every request while in development and using a singleton in production. Can't wait for this to get tested (:

Comment: You can [call `remove` with the template name on the wheezy.templates instance to remove the cached entry](https://github.com/akornatskyy/wheezy.template/blob/a5c470d0b7ddb92b02db64c5b2c936d6f9a5f8e0/src/wheezy/template/engine.py#L75) - so you can combine this with your file watcher and make wheezy recompile it if the template changes. In production you usually end up with restarting the application on deploy anyway, so it isn't really an issue.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem and the problem is with WatchFiles.

In the [watchfiles documentation](https://watchfiles.helpmanual.io/api/watch/#watchfiles.watch--force-polling) it is understood that the detection relies on file system notifications, and I think that via docker its events are not launched when using a volume.

> Notify will fall back to file polling if it can't use file system notifications

So you have to tell watchfiles to force the polling, that's what you did in your test python script with the parameter `force_polling` and that's why it works:

```python
for changes in watch('/code', force_polling=True):
```

Fortunately in the documentation we are given the possibility to force the polling via an environment variable.
Add this environment variable to your `docker-compose.yml` and auto-reload will work:

```yaml
services:
  fastapi-dev:
    image: myimagename:${TAG:-latest}
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/code
      - ./static:/static
      - ./templates:/templates
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "${HTTP_PORT:-8080}:80"
    environment:
      - WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING=true
```

Comment: Alright. I tried and tested again. And what can I say?…I don't know why, but all of a sudden everything works as it ought to. That is with or without `WATCHFILES_FORCE_POLLING` set to `true`.
E.g. `uvicorn package.main:app --proxy-headers --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --reload --reload-dir "/code" --reload-dir "/templates" --reload-include *.html` now works as I had hoped it would a month ago when it didn't. I have no clue as to what has changed in the meantime. Maybe this was fixed with the new FastAPI version?

Comment: I'm also using the latest version of FastAPI but I still have the problem, maybe it's related to the Docker version too, no idea! Anyway, I'm happy for you that everything is working again!

Comment: It's sort of working for me, but there is about a 20 second delay until the file change is picked up and the app is reloaded. Which makes it borderline workable.

Answer (score 1):

You can also include flag "--reload-dir /working-directory-name" and it will automatically reload the app.
Note, that you can also start your server in runtime from the python code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
uvicorn.run(
    "main:app",
    host=settings.MICROSERVICE_HOST,
    port=settings.MICROSERVICE_PORT,
    reload=True,
    reload_dirs=['/microservice']
)
```